# Probability distribution for the sum of two variables (binomial and uniform) - Specify distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a stochastic variable $X \sim R(0,1)$ - Thus $F_X(x) = 1$ if $x \in ]0,1[$ otherwise $0$

Let $Z$ be a stochastic variable, independent of $X$, $Z \sim b(1, 1/2)$.

$$P(Z = 0) = P(Z = 1) = 1/2$$

Let $U = X + Z$

Find distribution function of $U$. $F_U(u) = P(U \leq u) = P(X + Z \leq u)$

Prove that the distribution is $R(0,2)$

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours now, but can write the solution down.
Intuitively $U$ will be distribued $R(0,2)$ since every real number $]0,1[$ $[1,2[$ has equal change by the fact $Z \sim b(1, 1/2)$

Please give me some advice and sketch out how to solve the problem.

Best regards
Nicolas

Comment: Please fix your formulas using LaTeX, e.g. `$X\sim R(0,1)$` gives you $X\sim R(0,1)$. What is the distribution class $R$?

Comment: Thanks, never tried LaTeX but I will look into it.

The distribution class $R(0,1)$ it the real numbers $]0,1[$

It just means that every real number in this interval is mapped to $density = 1$ using the mass-density function $f_X(x)$

Comment: The [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)), you mean?

Comment: Exactly, sorry im not very specific - this is my first course in probability as a "freshmen"

Comment: Good luck then! There is a hint given to you in an answer, try using it and let us now whether it helped.

Comment: Your use of notation is ambiguous. If $F$ denotes the **cumulative probability density function** (CDF) of a random variable, since you say $F_U(u) = P(U \leq u)$, then $F_X(x) = 1$ for $0 < x < 1$ is _incorrect_; for a random variable uniformly distributed on $]0,1[$, $F_X(x) = P(X\leq x)$ equals $x$, not $1$ for $x \in ]0,1[$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove that
$$\forall u \in [0,1],\quad P(U \leq u) = P(X \leq u,\; Z = 0)$$
and
$$\forall u \in [0,1],\quad P(1 <U \leq 1 + u) = P(X \leq u,\; Z = 1)$$

Comment: But $u \in [0,2]$ right ?

Comment: As you mentioned in the OP, it is convenient to split up the the interval.

Comment: $P(X<=u, Z=0)$ is equal to the integral with upper bound $u$ and lower bound $0$ of $fX(x) * 1/2$ due to independence right ?

And $P(X<=u, Z=1)$ will always be $1/2$ ? If $Z = 1$ then $X < u$ since $u = X + Z$ and $X \in ]0,1[$

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Because of independence, $P(X \leq u, Z = 0) = P(X \leq u)P(Z=0) = \int_0^udx \times \frac{1}{2} = ...$

Comment: I think I get it, although i think splitting the interval up make it more confusing, since $u \in ]0,2[$ I appreciate your help guys.

Comment: I find probability equal to $1/2u$ when $ Z=0, Z=1$ - this means that $u$ on both intervals have probaility $1/2u$ - Should I do anything more now ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: You must recover $P(U \leq u)$ when $1 < u \leq 2$.

Comment: Exactly, thats done like this?: $P(X \leq u, Z = 1)$ -> The integral of $f_X(x)$ with boundaries $u$ and $0$ multiplied by $1/2$ because of independence.
If im wrong, would you show it to me ? Im having a hard time getting my head around this.

Comment: Or when $1 \le u \leq 2$ then $P(U \leq u) = P(X \leq u - 1, Z=1) $ ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: There was a mistake in my previous comment: for $1 < u \leq 2$, we have $P(U \leq u) = P(1 < U \leq 1 + (u-1)) \mathbf{+} P(U \leq 1)$. What you wrote is wrong because you forget the case where $Z = 0$.